# add fields having similar values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a trading model which has got 2 fields, number_of_share and price_per_share.

I want to showcase it in a pie chart and to do that I have to find all the trading objects associated with a user and then add all the trading objects which have same price_per_share and add their number_of_shared as well.

Example :-

```
trading id: 1, price_per_share: 10, number_of_shares: 20
trading id: 2, price_per_share: 10, number_of_shares: 12
trading id: 3, price_per_share: 12, number_of_shares: 10
```

now i want to add all the price_per_share which have got similar values (10 in this case). How can I do that ?

Comment: What is the expected output (in code), and what did you try to get it?

Comment: expected output is 32 shares @ 10 and 10 shares @12

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
Trading.group(:price_per_share).sum(:number_of_shares)
# => {10=>32, 12=>10}
```

The SQL will be something like:

```
SELECT SUM(`tradings`.`number_of_shares`) AS sum_number_of_shares, price_per_share AS price_per_share FROM `tradings` GROUP BY `tradings`.`price_per_share`
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope I understand that right, but:

```
Trading.where(:price_per_share => 10).sum(:number_of_shares)
```

should give you the result you are looking for.

Comment: I want to add all price_per_share which are similar, I will not know the value of price_per_share

Comment: Could you define "similar"? As you say it you first want to get a list of possible values like you would get with "distinct" or "group_by"?

Comment: this is the output which I want 32 shares @ 10 and 10 shares @12